# JPA and MySQL not syncron after database change

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

i use JPA-eclipseLink 2.5.0, Glassfish 4.1, MySQL, Eclipse Luna 4.4.0, Java8

i already create mydatabase and create entity

everything work fine

then i change some table, and some attribute in database, then problem happen

when i start to run my application it give me this error

```
cannot Deploy monsterpuzzle deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [monsterpuzzle] : Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MonsterPuzzle] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit. Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException Descriptor Exceptions: 

--------------------------------------------------------- Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-
9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [PRICE.ITEMID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only. Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[item] Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.Price --> [DatabaseTable(PRICE)])
```

based on the error i think the error is the mapping relation for table 'PRICE',

but i already delete table 'PRICE' and the entity, so i think my application didn't know that i already change some data..

i already check my entity many time, i think there's no problem with it.

i think the problem is .. my project still use the old connection and i need to refresh it

i already clean, build, re-publish my project, flush connection pool, create new connection pool, restart glassfish, restart my pc. but it still give me the same error

any help?

forgive my english thanks

EDIT 2 :

persistence configuration (persistence.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MonsterPuzzle" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>GameMonsterPuzzle</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

to get entity manager i use this code

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DaoBoxBattle extends DaoGeneric<Boxbattle>{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MonsterPuzzle")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return em;
    }

    public DaoBoxBattle(){
        super(Boxbattle.class);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add your `persistence.xml` and the code where you obtain the `EntityManager`.

Comment: @unwichtich i add persistence.xml and my code to obtain the entity manager.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other references to the PRICE table in your project?

Comment: @unwichtich i sure sir.. i already check it many time, also already delete all of my entity.. then let eclipse generate all entity from database... but i still get the same error.. my project & database don't have any words or class about PRICE.. but eclipse keep telling there's error in entity PRICE

Comment: Very strange. This definitely looks like a caching problem, but if you already restarted everything, this shouldn't happen. Maybe you can create a new project and copy your existing classes to that project to see if Eclipse/Glassfish/Deployment is working in general.

Comment: The error states the persistence unit is finding a model.Price entity, so check that you don't have an old version of your class on the classpath somehow. Do a manual search in your project/server for the Price.class file, as if you deleted the java class for the entity, you might might have left behind the class file.

Comment: @Chris i already check it sir.. inside eclipse, inside my workspace, inside glassfish there's no thing about Price. i end up creating new project and  new connection pool, its working fine now